# Processing array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, forms, html-input

I got this 2 array in a form to be process. However, i only manage to get the output from only one of the array. Sample as below :

`<inputs id="location" type="text" name="data[]" value=""/>` 
`<input id="shipval" type="text" name="data[][id]" value=""/>`

And in the PHP part is below :

```
foreach ($_POST ["data"] as $id => $subs) {       

            foreach ($subs as $key=>$sub) {

                $subcategory = $sub;

                if($subs['id']=="$subcategory"){
                    echo $sql = " insert into x(kodLebuhraya,kodSeksyen) values ('".$subs['id']."','".$sub."')";echo "<br>";    
                }else{
                    //echo "hi2";
                    echo $sql = " insert into x(kodLebuhraya,kodSeksyen) values ('".$subs['id']."','".$sub."')";echo "<br>";
                }

            }   

        }
```

It means one location for one shipval. i have multiple input field for location and shipval. Can you guys enlight me which one is wrong. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: thats really bizzare what you trying to do here is .... data[] is a simple string in input location case and data[] is array in shipval case ... show how can one element be array and string at the same time.. change your input name method

Comment: Do you have idea i could done this ? i have no idea to solve this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So basically you need to pass location and shipval in pairs.

Try this structure in HTML:

```
<label>Set One</label>
<input class="location" type="text" name="data[location][]" value=""/>
<input class="shipval" type="text" name="data[shipval][]" value=""/>
<label>Set Two</label>
<input class="location" type="text" name="data[location][]" value=""/>
<input class="shipval" type="text" name="data[shipval][]" value=""/>
<label>Set Three</label>
<input class="location" type="text" name="data[location][]" value=""/>
<input class="shipval" type="text" name="data[shipval][]" value=""/>
```

And this code for PHP:

```
  foreach ($_POST['data']['location'] as $key => $location) {       
        $shipVal = $_POST['data']['shipval'][$key];

        //now you have a pair of $location and $shipVal
        echo $location.' : '.$shipVal.'<hr>';

    }
```

Avoid using named indexes after unnamed ones ex. `<input name="array[][named]" />` you can lose order of fields if one of pair fields is empty.

Comment: I've try your code. And change the <inputs> for the form to input. but i get nothing for the output. Already try echo the location and the shipval. Any idea?

Comment: Corrected the syntax in the `$_POST` array. @muhamad-azam if you are going to be using multiple inputs like this you should not use id="location" or id="shipval" as those must be unique so you might want to use class attributes instead.

Comment: Ok thanks! I got this working now. Thanks you very much for those who helping me on this .

Answer (score 0):

You have `<inputs id="location"` instead of `<input id="location"`

Also... `foreach ($subs as $key => $sub) {` will throw an error for `<inputs id="location" type="text" name="data[]" value=""/>` because it is not multidimensional. So try changing that  to `<inputs id="location" type="text" name="data[][]" value=""/>`

Comment: if this is copy/pasted code: good catch, this is undoubtedly the issue.  +1

Comment: Might be worth noting it actually throws a warning - which *may* be why it wasn't noticed, if warnings are not being shown.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple select, the name has to end in square brackets, so you'll need to change the name of your `shipval` inputs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have writtten `inputs` instead of `input`.

Secondly, this line:

`foreach ($subs as $key=>$sub) {`

will treat each variable as an array, but the location isn't an array.

Comment: I didn't get it..what do you mean by "will treat each variable as an array, but the location isn't an array". any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I did not see the need for a loop since you want to just access `$_POST['data'][0]` and `$_POST['data'][1]['id']`

I also noticed that your SQL is a duplicate so you can try You can try

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO  x(`kodLebuhraya`,`kodSeksyen`) VALUES ('%s','%s')" ;
printf($sql,mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['data'][0]),mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['data'][1]['id']));
```

Output

```
INSERT INTO x(`kodLebuhraya`,`kodSeksyen`) VALUES ('A','B')
```

Form Used

```
<form method="POST">
    A : <input id="location" type="text" name="data[]" value="" /> 
    B : <input id="shipval" type="text" name="data[][id]" value="" /> 
    <input  id="shipval" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: first of all main problem is in input field names he wont get any id reason::: assume scenario his location is like  data[0] = 'london' from locations then lets say id should be 5 then data[0][id] = 5... look at this how can data[0] can be string value and assoc array at same time

Comment: @Surace that was just the basic issue but have updated my answer with the form i used

Comment: Hi,Basically i have multiple input for location and shipval. And it will be pair of it. Means one location for one shipval. how if i have 4 input location for location and shipval? What will the code will be?